# How to determine the concentration of citric acid in a carbonated drink

Tags: titration

How to determine the concentration of citric acid in a carbonated drink? Does it make sense to use titration if the soda is heavily colored? Or is it possible to get citric acid salt somehow?

Comment: Very important: Must leave drink opened in order to ensure complete decarbonation and minimum dissolved CO2. Read here: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/264159629_Determination_of_Citric_acid_in_Soft_drinks_Juice_drinks_and_Energy_drinks_using_Titration

Comment: is it possible to precipitate acetic acid using calcium hydroxide somehow?

Comment: I haven’t read the whole paper I linked, but your comment seems off-topic and out-of-the-blue. Could you tell me how it is linked to the post please?

Comment: perhaps there is a way to precipitate citrate acid from soda without using titration

Comment: Soda does not have acetic acid AFAIK

Comment: I meant a carbonated drink like coca cola

Comment: if you add calcium hydroxide to carbonated drink, won't you get calcium citrate that can be filtered out

Comment: I made a typo I wanted to say citric acid

Comment: There can be precipitated calcium carbonate too, from remaining CO2 or HCO3^- . // Are you interested in citric  acid alone, or in total citrates? As for usual pH, acid will not be IMHO the majority form.

Comment: but the resulting calcium citrate can react with sulfuric acid, this will restore the pH and release citric acid

Comment: High Pressure LC, anyone?

Answer (score 2):

The determination of citric acid in carbonated soda is not an easy task because you have at least three different acids, (aq) carbon dioxide, small amounts of phosphoric acid and then citric acid, tons of sugar, and color. Most of the online teaching experiments which rely on simply titration are erroneous. If we simply titrated a soft drink with a base without any pre-treatment/sample preparation, the result is total acidity not citric acid concentration! You cannot use a calcium salt because calcium phosphate and calcium citrate will partially precipitate out. The proper procedure for soft drink analysis is ion chromatography. Only specialized labs have this facility.

If the experiment is to do a simple titration, just call it total acidity.

Answer (score 0):

Citric acid solutions can be titrated by potassium permanganate, as citric acid is $\ce{CHOH(CH2COOH)2}$. It has a central alcohol group which is oxidized into a ketone group by $\ce{MnO4^-}$ ions at boiling temperature. It produces acetonedicarboxylic acid $\ce{CO(CH2COOH)2}$. This technique was used in old literature, like the French book "Guide de chimie biologique", Dunod, Paris, 1913". Unfortunately not too many practical details are given in this book.

Comment: Idea is nice but this will not work in the presence of sugar.